# How to use an external javascript file to call on function when a html button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a button that will add text when clicked. It works when the javascript is in the html file but does not when I link it externally.

HTML:

```
<input id="ex" type="text">
<button onclick="createList()">Create List</button>
<p id="demo">Click button</p>
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

Javascript:

```
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
      function createList() {
        var x = document.getElementById("ex").value;
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
      }
    })
```

Comment: What do you mean with link it externally?

Comment: Do you have any errors in the console?

Comment: There is no need to nest your `creatList()` function in a `DOMContentLoaded` event handler. Just add your `<script>` reference to the HTML page, right before the closing `body` tag and the script need only contain your `createList()` function. Also, the way your reference is set up, `app.js` must be in the same directory as the HTML page.

Answer (score 2):

By declaring your `createList()` function inside the event callback, you are actually scoping this function to the callback itself. You can just declare it as a function in your base javascript and it should be all good.

Before :

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
function createList() {
    var x = document.getElementById("ex").value;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
```

After :

```
function createList() {
  var x = document.getElementById('ex').value;
  document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = x;
}
```

If you want to wait for the DOM to be loaded before you declare your function, then you should attach your listener inside of the event callback like this :

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  document.getElementById('myButton').onclick = function() {
    var x = document.getElementById('ex').value;
    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = x;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

createList is inside another function (arrow function of addEventListener), so it is not accessible in your html.

put it out of `addEventListener`

or another way - do onclick attachment inside `addEventListener`, not in html, like:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  document.getElementById('myButton').onclick = function() {
    var x = document.getElementById("ex").value;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this

```
<input id="ex" type="text">
<button onclick="createList()">Create List</button>
<p id="demo">Click button</p>
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

APP.JS

```
  function createList() {
    var x = document.getElementById("ex").value;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
  }
```